# How to make Whatsapp share box

Tags: javascript, html, css, whatsapp

Working on a new website, with an option to share the page: I made the Facebook share with image and title description etc...

Now I want to make a **Whatsapp** share too, but when I look in **Whatsapp** API I see only text mention.

But I see places that do make share box on whatsapp...

Here some image example I found in google images:

[image]

Please help me understand how to define this and make a href button of it

Thanks!

Comment: There is no official Whatsapp API you could use for sending messages from a PC. The only "API" Whatsapp provides is the sharing API for mobile phones and the "whatsapp://" protocol - which does only work on clients having Whatsapp installed.

Comment: I know - but how I make a "whatsapp://" href that make thumbnail and title&description&link + costum text...?

Comment: Added more details as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official Whatsapp API you could use for sending messages from a PC. The only "API" Whatsapp provides is the sharing API for mobile phones and the `whatsapp://` protocol - which does only work on clients having Whatsapp installed.

Using that `whatsapp://` protocol, you can send a message containing text-only.
Whatsapp will automatically resolve contained URLs and display image and title according to the screenshot you linked.

Taking a look at the [example at crunchify](http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-social-sharing-button-without-any-plugin-and-script-loading-wordpress-speed-optimization-goal/), they do exactly the same thing.

```
$whatsappURL = 'whatsapp://send?text='.$crunchifyTitle . ' ' . $crunchifyURL;
```

What will result in exactly the output contained in your screenshot.